# Calling LINQ Extension Methods over a SqliteDataReader

Tags: linq, sqlite, c#-4.0, datareader

I'm trying to handle output from a `SQLiteDataReader` and I was wondering, on the one hand, why I'm unable to call the `Take<>` extension method over the reader (as apparently there´s a `System.Data.SQLite.Linq` assembly), and on the other hand, if there's a perhaps better way to deal with the results of a reader as a whole as I'm planning to implement generic CRUD methods for those.

```
using (var con = new SQLiteConnection(str.ConnectionString))
{
    con.Open();
    using (var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sql, con))
    {
        using (SQLiteDataReader data = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (data.HasRows)
            {
                var txt = new StringBuilder();
                while (data.Read())
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < data.FieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        txt.AppendFormat("{0} ", data.GetValue(i));
                    }
                    txt.AppendLine(Environment.NewLine);
                }
                Console.WriteLine(txt.ToString());
            }
            data.Close();
        }
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

For the extension method to work I've tried something like:

```
txt.AppendFormat("{0} ", Convert.ToString(data.GetValue(i)).Take(10));
```

But the string gets populated with types instead.

Any advice will be definitely appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance.